# Does (and how) a shark fin on car top (or fan blade) reduce drag?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, aerodynamics, turbulence

I've heard this kind of shark fin on the roof reduces drag by breaking the wave that forms behind, where the roof bends into rear window.

[image]

*[image source](https://www.carmagazine.co.uk/car-news/first-official-pictures/bmw/m3/)*

The story goes that it's similar to [these fins on fan blades](https://www.quietpc.com/zm-f1-plus-sf), that are claimed to reduce fan noise.

[image]

*Noctua fan. [source](https://technogog.com/review/review-of-noctua-nf-s12a-pwm-120mm-cooling-fan/)*

Is there any paper or simulation images that show how this fin works, and what effects are?

Comment: Isn't this device used to house an antenna? So it doesn't "flop" in the wind which reduces signal quality? It's hard to imagine _that_ would have an appreciable aerodynamic effect on the car.

Comment: Yes, it's an antenna, but story goes that it breaks the laminar wave, like in [this fan](https://www.quietpc.com/zm-f1-plus-sf). That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Those fins are a lot larger in relative size. I know there are some cars that have a larger shark fin blade to improve stability while turning, and direct air flow to the wing to further improve rear wheel traction. Are those the shark fins you mean?

Comment: @josephh I've updated the image, to show exactly the one I mean. Regarding fan blades, I've seen smaller ones, relatively equal to the BMW fin.

Comment: Do car manufacturers actually claim that the antenna fin is for aerodynamic performance/stability/etc?

Comment: @KyleKanos I haven't found such claims. It's a story from a tech guy, and I can't verify where he took it from.